# VB.NET - Doing work in separate thread to prevent Form from hanging

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a really simple form with a button that fires a Sub I created which gathers data from ActiveDirectory and adds it to an Excel Sheet.

The problem is, when I click this button the whole form hangs. So I figured the operation that gathers the data and adding it to the Excel sheet should be run in it's own thread, so that the form won't hang. Possibly it would be great to add a progressbar as well.
The progressbar however is located at the Main userform that starts up once the projects is run.

What do I need to do in order to get this the way I want?

Edit: Added some of my code. I've got one MainForm.vb and one CodeFile.vb.
I want most of the code in the CodeFile.vb so it's tidier.

MainForm.vb

```
Imports User_edit.CodeFile
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub btnImportData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImportData.Click
        If MyBackgroundWorker.IsBusy <> True Then
            MyBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles MyBackgroundWorker.DoWork
        ExportADUsers()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles MyBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
        statusBarLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles MyBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        statusBarLabel.Text = "Finished"
    End Sub
End Class
```

CodeFile.vb

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Module CodeFile
    Public Sub ExportADUsers()
        MainForm.MyBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        MainForm.MyBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        Dim i As Integer

        Dim objRootDSE, strRoot, strfilter, strAttributes, strScope
            objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
            strRoot = objRootDSE.GET("DefaultNamingContext")
            strfilter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User))"
            strAttributes = "mail,userPrincipalName,givenName,sn," & _
              "initials,displayName,physicalDeliveryOfficeName," & _
              "telephoneNumber,mail,wWWHomePage,profilePath," & _
              "scriptPath,homeDirectory,homeDrive,title,department," & _
              "company,manager,homePhone,pager,mobile," & _
              "facsimileTelephoneNumber,ipphone,info," & _
              "streetAddress,postOfficeBox,l,st,postalCode,c"
            'Scope of the search.  Change to "onelevel" if you didn't want to search child OU's
            MainForm.statusBarLabel.Text = "Collecting data"
        strScope = "subtree"

            Dim cn, cmd, rs
            cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

            cn.open("Provider=ADsDSOObject;")
            cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
            cmd.commandtext = "<LDAP://" & strRoot & ">;" & strfilter & ";" & _
                                strAttributes & ";" & strScope

            rs = cmd.EXECUTE

            Dim objExcel, objWB, objSheet

            objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
        objSheet = objWB.Worksheets(1)

        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            MainForm.MyBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i * 10)
            objSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
            objSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Font.Bold = True
        Next

            Dim strExportFile
            strExportFile = "C:\users\vsando\desktop\export.xls"

            objSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
            objSheet.SaveAs(strExportFile)

            'Clean up
            rs.Close()
            cn.Close()
            objSheet = Nothing
            objWB = Nothing
            objExcel.Quit()
            objExcel = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Notice the `ExportFromAD` Sub I've got in the `CodeFile.vb`. This is what is actually doing the work. In the For each loop that adds data to the Excel is where I've put the `MainForm.MyBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i * 10)`.

Problem is, it doesn't actually update the label on the form. Which I find pretty weird because the form isn't really hanging or anything. Is it trying to access a different thread or something? Meaning, the form is run on it's own thread which can't be accessed from my second thread?

Comment: You've already got the answer in one of your tags: the easiest way to do this is using a `BackgroundWorker` component. The [sample implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is already very good.

Comment: From the example code: `If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then` … yuck! Yet again they let an intern write the example.

Comment: @Konrad: Yuck, I agree. But it's more likely that they've done that in a vain attempt to "clarify" the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) since this class is designed for this precise use-case.

This also allows you to [call back to the form to update the status bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx).

Comment: Please see the updated topic. I've tried adding the Background Worker. And I think it is working, but I can't get the progress bar or statusstrip label to actually update. I tried adding a break point to see the actual value of the label at runtime. And it is in fact set. It just doesn't show. Which is why I believe it's trying to display the label which is on a different thread?

Answer (score 2):

The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class is what you need to use. For passing data back to the form's progress bar you set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to true and handle the `ProgressChanged` event to set the progress bar's value. From the long running method you can send progress like this:

```
backgroundworker.ReportProgress(10)
```